# Simplifying $\frac{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{8}}{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{4}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I don't understand the method for simplifying this expression:

$$\frac{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{8}}{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{4}}$$

where this is used as a step of the simplification

$$\frac{e^\frac{i\pi}{16}}{e^\frac{i\pi}{16}}*\frac{e^\frac{i\pi}{8}}{e^\frac{i\pi}{8}}*\frac{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{8}}{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{4}}$$

and we end up with this

$$e^\frac{i\pi}{16}*\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{16}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{8}}$$

how do I know that I can use

$$\frac{e^\frac{i\pi}{16}}{e^\frac{i\pi}{16}}*\frac{e^\frac{i\pi}{8}}{e^\frac{i\pi}{8}}$$

as part of the method?

Comment: Note that if $a=\exp \frac{-i\pi}{8}$, then $a^2=\exp \frac{-i\pi}{4}$, then fraction is $\frac{1-a}{1-a^2}=\frac{1}{1+a}$. Further simplification can be $\frac{1}{1+a}=\frac{1}{2}a^{-1/2}\frac{2}{a^{-1/2}+a^{1/2}}$. $a^{1/2}=\exp \frac{-i\pi}{16}$, then $\frac{2}{a^{-1/2}+a^{1/2}}=\left(\frac{\exp \frac{-i\pi}{16}+\exp \frac{i\pi}{16}}{2}=\right)^{-1}=\sec \frac{\pi}{16}$, then result is $\frac{1}{2} \exp \frac{i\pi}{16} \sec \frac{\pi}{16}$.

Comment: Bonus question, can we show easily that $\Re(x)=\frac 12$ ? We can develop trig lines of pi/8 but this is quite ugly after rationalization of the denominator... So I'm wondering if this can be done via another idea. $x=\frac 12-i(\frac 12+\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}})$

Answer (score 2):

If $x = \exp(\frac{-i\pi}{8})$, then we are interested in
$$
\frac{1-x}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1}{1+\exp(\frac{-i\pi}{8})} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{8}}{1-e^\frac{-i\pi}{4}}=\frac{e^\frac{-i\pi}{8}}
{e^\frac{-i\pi}{4}}\cdot\frac{e^\frac{i\pi}{8}-1}{e^\frac{i\pi}{4}-1}=e^\frac{i\pi}{8}\cdot\frac{e^\frac{i\pi}{16}\left(e^\frac{i\pi}{16}-e^\frac{-i\pi}{16} \right)}{e^\frac{i\pi}{8}\left(e^\frac{i\pi}{8}-e^\frac{-i\pi}{8} \right)}=e^\frac{i\pi}{16}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{16} \right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)}.$

I hope my calculations is correct and could help you.